vanillajs-datepicker does not set input value, no change event triggered on date click
I'm using this datepicker and I like it but its not triggering the change event on an input after I click a date.
Here is my code
I  tested this on jsFiddle


const elem = document.querySelector('input[name="foo"]');
const datepicker = new Datepicker(elem, {
  autohide: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
});

elem.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanillajs-datepicker@1.3.4/dist/css/datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanillajs-datepicker@1.3.4/dist/js/datepicker-full.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="foo">



When I click the specific date on the datepicker the change event is not triggered.
I need help with this.
I'm also using it with livewire and alpine but after clicking the date the change even is not triggered. here is my laravel code

When I tested pickaday it works.
How can I work around this or make it to trigger the change even on vanillajs datepicker.
Thanks in advance.

Datepicker doesn't trigger the native onchange event

ok I thought  I was doing something wrong, is there a way to trigger the event myself like set the value manually so that the event can be triggered.

Your library won't trigger a native event like onchange which is why is not working. You have to use the library custom event instead
Info in the documentation
changedate


const elem = document.querySelector('input[name="foo"]');
const datepicker = new Datepicker(elem, {
  autohide: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
});

elem.addEventListener("changeDate", function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanillajs-datepicker@1.3.4/dist/css/datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanillajs-datepicker@1.3.4/dist/js/datepicker-full.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="foo">




np, glad to be of help
